# Drag drop issues when items dragged away

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Here's the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HnQWU/

When items are removed from a category, and that category has no items.. it does not allow to have items dragged back under the empty category.

What it is needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once empty the height of the `ul` is 0 making it impossible to drag over.  You can use `min-height` to make the `ul` still take up some space when empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/HnQWU/1/

NOTE: blue border added to illustrate what is happening.

Comment: It's always the things you don't think about :)  Thank you very much.